# Github actions ci/cd throwing error - Error: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Tags: github-actions, cicd, tibco

I am trying to create CI/CD of a tibco application, below is my yaml file for github actions

```
name: DEV workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "dev" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "dev" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
 
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean 

    # Optional: Uploads the full dependency graph to GitHub to improve the quality of Dependabot alerts this repository can receive
    - name: Update dependency graph
      uses: advanced-security/maven-dependency-submission-action@571e99aab1055c2e71a1e2309b9691de18d6b7d6
```

in the "Build with maven" section its getting stucked and throwing error :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.066 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-07T17:03:24Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/runner/work/tibco-sample/tibco-sample). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Am not able to find this location (/home/runner/work/tibco-sample/tibco-sample) to check if pom file exist or not

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Where is your `.pom` file located? Please add that to your question. Thanks!

Comment: The /home/runner/work/tibco-sample/tibco-sample path is the normal workspace folder for a runner, where the checkout action does its work. Running an ‘ls’ after the checkout should show your pin file. Otherwise double check the branch that you’re in and if het has the correct file in the root.